# What is the better solution to format/restrict *-input entry in Polymer 1.0

Tags: dart-polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-elements

I would like to know if exists best practices to format and restrict on *-input elements entry in Polymer 1.0.

For example:

- Number/Currency = '999.999.999,99'
- Date = 'dd/mm/yyyy'

  1. Is there a `pattern` default to guarantee that entry just number, comma and points?
  2. Is there some form to format the display, similar to expressions filter in OLD-Polymer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iron-input` supports an `allowed-pattern` attribute https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-input

Comment: Ok, for valid input. But is there a form to use mask (formating) like '999.999,00'? For example, user enter with 5 and input display to user '5,00' or user enter to 5 dot 2 and input display '5,20'

Comment: I don't know about that. You might take a look at the source of the gold-*-input elements and build a similar custom input element.